how to show embeded video on home page from blog page in wagtail?
As shown i can embed the video via URL. but it save videos as url and text as whole body. i an unable to extract videos only and show in home page.
https://docs.wagtail.org/en/v4.0.3/editor_manual/new_pages/inserting_videos.html#
i tried using
from wagtail.core.rich_text import RichText

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='extract_videos')
def extract_videos(body):
    videos = []
    # Check if the body content is RichText
    if isinstance(body, RichText):
        # Iterate through each block in the RichText
        for block in body:
            # Check if the block is of type 'embed'
            if block.block_type == 'embed':
                # Append the value (which should be the embedded video URL) to the videos list
                videos.append(block.value)
    return videos

